# Serialization fails with custom Torch class

Tags: torch

Serialization can fails with a class object created containing `__pairs`:

```
test = torch.class('test')
function test:__init()
  self.data = {}
end

function test:__pairs(...)
    return pairs(self.data, ...)
end

function test:get_data()
  print(self.data)
end

a = test.new()
a.data = {"asdasd"}
b = torch.serialize(a)
c = torch.deserialize(b)
print(torch.typename(c))
print(c:get_data())
```

The following returns:

```
test
nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The engine behind the `torch.serialization` is located in the [File-class](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/file.md). The [`File:writeObject`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/5f9c863c629a729e0b649c8c8de3f1a38cdb2742/File.lua#L107-L243) us the key function. For the above example the action for a Torch class starts at [line 201](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/5f9c863c629a729e0b649c8c8de3f1a38cdb2742/File.lua#L201) with the:

```
elseif typeidx == TYPE_TORCH then
```

The type is identified in the [`File:isWritableObject`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/5f9c863c629a729e0b649c8c8de3f1a38cdb2742/File.lua#L28-L47).

One could probably implement the metatable function [`write`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/5f9c863c629a729e0b649c8c8de3f1a38cdb2742/File.lua#L208-L210) but in the above example the problem was non-torch metatable function `__pairs` that should be `__pairs__` (see [`torch.getmetatable`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/utility.md#torch.getmetatable)):

```
test = torch.class('test')
function test:__init()
  self.data = {}
end

function test:__pairs__(...)
    return pairs(self.data, ...)
end

function test:get_data()
  print(self.data)
end

a = test.new()
a.data = {"asdasd"}
b = torch.serialize(a)
c = torch.deserialize(b)
print(torch.typename(c))
print(c:get_data())
```

This gives the expected:

```
test    
{
  1 : "asdasd"
}
```